# Proxy to other local webserver in node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy

i have following problem in my express application for now. I have different services with build in webserver running. The problem is now i need to access it following:

localhost:8888

The normal server can be accessed over localhost:3000.

Is it possible to create something like a proxy to have something like this.

- localhost:3000
- localhost:3000/admin/chronograf
- localhost:3000/admin/mongo

---

```
const express = require('express');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const app = express();

const proxyOptions = {
}

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(proxyOptions);
const serverOne = 'http://localhost:8888';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.all("/app1", function(req, res) {
  console.log('redirecting to Server1');
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

The Problem is that the page is showing put the links of the resources are not rewritten to the new path. I need a config value or some own Implementation to rewrite the urls.

thanks for helping

Comment: The links from content being delivered from the proxied host? A proxy does not "rewrite" urls within the content you deliver. If your problem is that links are not "relative" to `/app1` then you need to make the links "relative" in the markup produced.

Comment: @NeilLunn i know it. I think in nginx is something like this easy possible.

Comment: Fixing your markup is very possible. This is not a "proxy" problem, but a "markup" problem. Asking a process to "rewrite your markup" is pulling weeds with a chainsaw. Learn what `base` does and/or generally make your URL's "realtive" instead of **absolute**.

Comment: Than is the question how the basepath parameter works.
https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.3/administration/configuration/#p-basepath